# Share component not recognise device language

Tags: ios, react-native, localization, share

In react native `Share` component always open in english language. Even if I set italian language in system of iOS then also it display in english. Is there any option for set localise in share dialogue.

Here is the code and screenshot

```
let result = await Share.share(
        {
          message: text
          url: urlShare,
          title: abc
        },
        {
          dialogTitle: abc,
        },
      );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue, you need to add/update `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` in the **Info.plist**

By default `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` is set to **"en"**.
[image]

Simply replace `en` with `it`() or `it-ch`.
[image]

For multi language support, add this to Info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations</key>
<string>true</string>
```

Full documentation can be found [here](https://react-native-share.github.io/react-native-share/docs/language-support/)

Comment: Hey @chirag shah , kindly upvote my answer if you find it interesting and flag it as a solution if it solved the problem

Comment: Sure let me check

Comment: i have two language in our application then how i can manage this?